# How to assign a single equation number/label to *n* equations?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

I want to label

```
\begin{align*}
x\equiv & x_1(\text{mod } m_1)\\
x\equiv & x_2(\text{mod } m_2)\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
x\equiv & x_n(\text{mod } m_n)
\end{align*}
```

as one set of equations. How to do?

Answer (score 11):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
     x &\equiv x_1\pmod{m_1}\\
     x &\equiv x_2\pmod{m_2}\\
       &\enspace\vdots \\
     x &\equiv x_n\pmod{m_n}
     \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible refinement

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\mathtoolsset{
  shortvdotsadjustabove = 3pt,
  shortvdotsadjustbelow = 0pt,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x &\equiv x_1 \pmod{m_1} \\
x &\equiv x_2 \pmod{m_2} \\
  &\shortvdotswithin{\equiv}
x &\equiv x_n \pmod{m_n}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One `\vdots` instead of lines with single dots?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes. I just copied OP's code. Dangers of copy pasting :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you nest a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment. This will give you a single, vertically centered equation number.

I further suggest you use `\vdotswithin{=}` instead of `\enspace\vdots` to get correctly positioned vertical dots. (The `\vdotswithin` macro is provided by the `mathtools` package, a superset of the `amsmath` package.) `\vdotswithin` inserts a bit more vertical whitespace than `\shortvdotswithin` does; the latter directive is used in @HarishKumar's answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \vdotswithin macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
     x &\equiv x_1\pmod{m_1}\\
     x &\equiv x_2\pmod{m_2}\\
       &\vdotswithin{=} \\
     x &\equiv x_n\pmod{m_n}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```